# Are Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) applications allowed into the App Store?

Tags: ios, llvm, automatic-ref-counting

Since ARC will work in 4.0 are we able to compile our applications with LLVM3 now and put them into the App Store?

Or do we have to wait until Xcode 4.2 to release?

Comment: I'm voting to close as too localized, because the status of beta-level development tools will change over time.  Therefore, the answers here won't necessarily remain accurate.

Comment: However, it is general policy (read the release notes) that early stage prerelease development tools are not to be used for submission to the App Store.  Apple will tell you when things have stabilized enough with these tools that you are free to do so.

Comment: @PengOne How do you figure that an LLVM compiler technology (UNIX) and developer tools question belongs on the Apple consumer Q&A site?

Comment: @wjlafrance: I imagine that @PengOne meant this question should be asked of Apple directly, not on any consumer Q&A website.

Comment: @Sedate I still say this is a valid forum for asking this. LLVM has been released with ARC and it is not under NDA. Besides, Apple's devforums do not have nearly as good a community.

Answer (score 2):

There's no problem with submitting ARC enabled applications. You have just to sign and submit the app with XCode 4.1.

The runtime support for ARC is already there (current Snow Leopard and Lion versions have it built in already). And as you are allowed to use whatever tool you want to build your binaries there should be no problem with a binary built with the clang/llvm3 suite.

Answer (score 0):

If you manage to force Xcode 4.0.2 to compile with Clang from LLVM 3, I imagine you could. If you use the LLVM 3 backend, Apple may or may not detect this and invalidate your binary. Of course, you can't submit with 4.2 as the standard procedure is to only allow stable SDKs.